# 404 on Login and LogOff methods after setting up area routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC5 application using ASP Identity 2 and Fluentsecurity with the following methods in the Home controller which handle the log in page and logging out:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        this.ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return this.View();
    }

public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        this.AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return this.RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }
```

This works absolutely fine.

I now need to add an area into my application and set up routing accordingly. I have added a sub folder called 'Admin' under the 'Areas' folder and placed the relevant controllers and views in there in the appropriate subfolders.

I have then set up the routing as follows in Global.asax:

```
private static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "AppName.Web.Controllers " });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{querydata}",
            new { querydata = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "AppName.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });

    }
```

Which is then called as below:

```
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        SecurityConfigurator.Configure(SecurityConfig.Configure);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalApiFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("AppName.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers");

    }
```

If i then run the application, routing is working as expected in my area and the main application, apart from it seems to have broken the Login and LogOff methods in the aforementioned Home controller, now giving a 404 error when trying to access them. The index method of the same Home controller works fine though.

In case it's related to Fluentsecurity, this is how security is configured:

```
internal static void Configure(ConfigurationExpression configuration)
    {
        configuration.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
        configuration.GetRolesFrom(GetRoles);

        configuration.For<HomeController>(x => x.Login(default(string))).DenyAuthenticatedAccess();
        configuration.For<HomeController>(x => x.Index()).DenyAnonymousAccess();
        configuration.For<HomeController>(x => x.LogOff()).AllowAny();

        //Admin Home
        configuration.For<Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController>(x => x.Index()).DenyAnonymousAccess();

    }
```

Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score -2):

```
private static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{querydata}",
            new { querydata = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "AppName.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "AppName.Web.Controllers " });



    }
```